# Math Notations And Generalization Question

Tags: math

When you make a generalization like: A^n.B^m does that mean that the m can never be equal to n or can I have at least one value where they are equal like "AABB" for example?

Comment: Shouldn't it a better fit for math.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Note that Stack Overflow focuses on Programming; see [what's on-topic in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). However, Stack Overflow has [many sister sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites), so your question is probably a better fit for [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

This generalization allows for all combinations of *m* and *n* including *m* = *n*.